# CameraRoll don't show images on android in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I have this code in my react-native project

```
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
    first: 20,
    assetType: "Photos",
  }).then((answer) => {
      dispatch({
        type: PHOTOS_LIBRARY,
        photos: answer.edges,
      });
      console.log(answer.edges);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

And it work nice on my old android device, but don't work on emulator and more powerful devices, it not show photos, in fact, it return object of photos, but with null dimensions.
This console.log:

```
    [{"fileSize": null, "filename": null, "height": null, "id": 0, "playableDuration": null,
 "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200902_153713.jpg", "width": null}, 
{"fileSize": null, "filename": null, "height": null, "id": 1, "playableDuration": null, "uri":
 "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200902_153653.jpg", "width": null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using include in your CameraRoll.getPhotos () method?
Ex:

```
 CameraRoll.getPhotos({
  first: 25,
  assetType: 'Photos',
  include: ['filename', 'imageSize'],
})
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works, I already solve this problem)) Also, you need to import CameraRoll from @react-native-community/cameraroll

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem with galaxy A50 and SDK Version 29.

Fix this add this line in:  `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
...
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: This was helpful but when I added that in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` it failed. Instead, I had to add it to `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`